# Add new Item with ember.js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm try to add a new note in my application. I have "new" button in the index template and the actions: createNote in my Notes.NotesController but every time i press the button I get:
Uncaught Error: Nothing handled the event 'createNote'.

here my html

```
   [...]   
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">  
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="bar">
        <input type="text" class="search" />
        <div class="bar-buttons">
          <button {{action "createNote"}}> NEW </button>
          <button> HOME </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <aside>
        <h4 class="all-notes">All Notes {{length}}</h4>
          {{#each item in model}}
            <li>
              {{#link-to 'note' item}} {{item.title}} {{/link-to}}
            </li>
          {{/each}}
      </aside>
      {{outlet}}
    </div> 
</script>

 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="main"> 
   <section>
    <div class="note">
      {{input type="text" placeholder="Title" value=newTitle action="createNote"}}
      {{input type="text" placeholder="What you need to remember?" value=newBody action="createNote"}}
      {{input type="text" placeholder="Url:" value=newUrl action="createNote"}}
    </div>
   </section>
 </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="note"> 
    <section>
        <div class="note">
            {{#if isEditing}}
              <h2 class="note-title input-title"> {{edit-input-note value=title focus-out="modified" insert-newline="modified"}} </h2>
              <p class="input-body"> {{edit-area-note value=body focus-out="modified" insert-newline="modified"}} </p>
              {{edit-input-note value=url focus-out="modified" insert-newline="modified"}}
            {{else}}
              <h2 {{action "editNote" on="doubleClick"}} class="note-title" > {{title}} </h2>
              <button {{action "removeNote"}} class="delete"> Delete </button>
              <p {{action "editNote" on="doubleClick"}}> {{body}} </p>
              {{input type="text" placeholder="URL:" class="input"  value=url }}
            {{/if}}
        </div>
      </section>
  </script>
  [...]
```

Controller:

```
Notes.NotesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend ({
    events:{
        createNote: function () {
            var title = this.get('newTitle');
            if (!title.trim()) { return; }
            var body = this.get('newBody');
            var url = this.get('newUrl');

            var note = this.store.createRecord('note', {
                title: title,
                body: body,
                url: url
            });

            this.set('newTitle', '');
            this.set('newBody', '');
            this.set('newUrl', '');

            note.save();
        }
    }
});

Notes.NoteController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    actions:{
        editNote: function(){
            this.set('isEditing', true);
        },

        modified: function(){
            this.set('isEditing', false);
            this.get('model').save();
        },

        removeNote: function(){
            var note = this.get('model');
            this.transitionToRoute('main');
            note.deleteRecord();
            note.save();
        }
    },
    isEditing: false

});
```

Router:

```
Notes.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('index', { path: '/' }, function (){
        this.resource('main', {path: '/'});
        this.resource('note', { path: ':note_id' });
    });
});

Notes.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
     return this.store.find('note'); 
  }
});

Notes.MainRoute = Ember.Route.extend({ 
    model: function (){             
        return this.store.find('note'); 
    }
});

Notes.NotesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({ 
    model: function (){             
        return this.store.find('note'); 
    }
});
```

And the model:

```
Notes.Note = DS.Model.extend ({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    body: DS.attr('string'),
    url: DS.attr('string')
});

Notes.Note.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'hello world',
        body: 'ciao ciao ciao ciao',
        url: ''
    },
    {   
        id: 2,
        title: 'javascript frameworks',
        body: 'Backbone.js, Ember.js, Knockout.js',
        url: '...'

    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Find a job in Berlin',
        body: 'Monster, beralinstartupjobs.com',
        url: '...'
    }
]
```

View:

```
Notes.EditInputNoteView = Ember.TextField.extend({
  didInsertElement: function () {
    $(this).focus();
  }
});
Ember.Handlebars.helper('edit-input-note', Notes.EditInputNoteView);



Notes.EditAreaNoteView = Ember.TextArea.extend ({
    didInsertElement: function () {     
        $(this).focus();
    }
})
Ember.Handlebars.helper('edit-area-note', Notes.EditAreaNoteView);
```

Can someone direct me on the right path?
Thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actions belong in the actions hash, not in the events hash, additionally, your action link is in the index template, and your action (which is in the events) should be in the index controller/route

```
 Notes.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions:{
    createNote: function () {
        var title = this.get('newTitle');
        if (!title.trim()) { return; }
        var body = this.get('newBody');
        var url = this.get('newUrl');

        var note = this.store.createRecord('note', {
            title: title,
            body: body,
            url: url
        });

        this.set('newTitle', '');
        this.set('newBody', '');
        this.set('newUrl', '');

        note.save();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I can't see if your solutions works because now i get different error: Uncaught Error: Attempted to handle event `didSetProperty` on <Notes.Note:ember403:fixture-0> while in state root.deleted.saved. Called with {name: body, oldValue: undefined, originalValue: undefined, value: undefined}.  When I click on "new" button. I can't figured out what this error mean, what's wrong now?

Comment: And I also have a technical question, when I should use the ember-data? Is easier or more difficult develop app with ember-data?

Comment: Ember Data makes your life easier in the long run, it takes a little bit more setting up time, but it's totally worth it.

Comment: The other properties are probably out of scope at this point.

Comment: what do you mean with out of scope? I mean my real problem is to understand how to correctly create a new item since every time I got new errors probably the whole approach isn't right.

Comment: I fix my problem. The value where empty since i tried to save before actually adding text inside. Also now every template actions has own controller, and seem works fine. thank you!